# Python statement issue

Tags: python

I am  trying to create a question/answer program where the program asks a question from a file and then compares the answer but when I write the right one it still tells that its wrong.

```
import random

def Questionnaire():  
    a=1
    i=1
    while i <= 10 :
        with open("mcq.txt", "r") as r:
            list = r.readlines()
            questions = random.choice(list)
            questans = questions.split(";;")
            question, answer = questans[0], questans[1]
            print(f"Q{a} - {question}")
            a,i=a+1,i+1
            ans(answer) 

def ans(answer):
    mychoice =str(input("What is your answer ?"))
    if mychoice != answer :
        print(f"Wrong answer, the right one is : {answer} \n")
    else :
        print("Bravo, it is the right one ! \n")

Questionnaire()
```

Here in my second function, the if else statement returns always False, even when I changed to make !=
BTW the text page is like `Who was the first president of the USA? A-Trump B-Clinton C-Lincoln D-George Washington;;D` and it continues like so...

The file is like so

```
Who is the head of the new government in France in 1936? A-Thorez B-Blum C-Daladier D-Pétain ;; B
What is the slogan of the Popular Front? A- “With France, for the French” B- “liberty, equality, fraternity” C- “work, family, homeland” D- “bread, peace, freedom” ;; D
Which party does not make up the Popular Front? A-The Radical Party B-The SFIO C-The National Bloc D-The Communist Party ;; C
What event of 1934 contributed to the creation of the Popular Front? A-The Congress of Tours B-The riots of the leagues C-The Crash of Wall-Street D-The resignation of Clémenceau ;; B
What event is at the origin of the crisis of the 1930s? A-The Russian Revolution B-The Rise of Fascism C-The First World War D-The Wall Street Crash ;; D
Which of these countries is an island? A-France B-Netherlands C-Australia D-Korea ;; C
What is the color of Henri's white horse 4 A-Green B-Red C-Gray D-White ;; D
One byte corresponds to A-1bit B-4 bits C-8 bits D-32 bits ;; C
With 1 byte you can encode A-255 values ​​B-8 values ​​C-16 values ​​D-256 values ​​;; D
What is Microsoft Windows? A-A type of computer B-An operating system C-A database management system ;; B
The binary system uses the basis A-2 B-10 C-8 D-16 E-None of the above is true. ;; A
In Greco-Roman mythology, the gods gathered on A-Mount Sinai B-Vesuvius C-Mount Olympus ;; C
In Greek mythology, Pegasus is A-A winged horse B-A man with an eagle's head C-A giant ;; A
In what year was François Mitterrand elected President of the French Republic? A-1974 B-1976 C-1981 D-1986 ;; C
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a sample of the file so we can reproduce ?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: I put the file example, if you try with this it might be more accurate.

Comment: Put a `print(mychoice, answer)` before the if line to inspect the content of those variables. Pay attention to white space characters.

Comment: That is something that I looked up @Feodoran. The thing is, I even replaced any possible spaces with "", and checked the type of the the variables and both are 'str'

Comment: There are more white space characters then just spaces ;)

Comment: The thing is also, I want 10 questions form a 30 question file @azro, I forgot to mention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fix

The is because, when using `readlines()` it gives your a list of string ending by `\n` char, so the answer string becomes `A\n` that is different of `A`. Also sometimes there is a space before answer letter. Use `str.strip()` to remove both

```
question, answer = questans[0], questans[1].strip()
```

---

#### Improve

- you open and read the whole file at each iteration :  read once at beginning
- `random.choice` could give the same row at 2 different iteration :  use `random.shuffle` to randomize once, then take in order
- `a` and `i` does same, keep one
- use `enumerate` and a slice of your question list to do only X question

```py
def Questionnaire(nb_question=10):
    with open("test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as r:
        values = r.read().splitlines()  # don't keep ending \n

    random.shuffle(values)  # randomize once

    for i, questions in enumerate(values[:nb_question], start=1):
        question, answer = questions.split(";;")
        print(f"Q{i} - {question.strip()}")
        ans(answer.strip())
```

Comment: this answer actually works, thanks. I now understand the problem. That's why there was a space between when I printed to check.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @azro, I really appreciate it. The Improvement was very helpful.

Comment: I hope you are fine. I just realised that you wrote a ":" in [:nb_question] and how does the I goes from 1 to 10. I guess I didn't understood the enumerate function

Comment: @Miles that is a slice `list[:10]` keeps the first ten element read about slice. Then enumerate just allows to generates both the indice and the data

Comment: So I guess in this state, the indice is given to the variable I , and the data to questions